# How to call a CTE in a follow up IF statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I know that a CTE must be followed by a `SELECT`, `INSERT`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE` statement.

So how should I use this kind of logic in my procedure?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE st_exemple
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    (...)

    WITH CTE AS 
    (
        SELECT 
            'ID COTA'   = TABEL1.ID_COTA,
            'NM CLIENT' = TABLE2.NM_CLIENT
        FROM 
            (...)
        WHERE
            (...)
    );

    IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CTE) = 0
    BEGIN
        SET @COMMENT = 'SELECT WTIHOUT DATA'
        GOTO END_PROC
    END;
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @COMMENT = 'SELECT WITH DATA';
        GOTO END_PROC
    END;
```

I want to create a variable with the observation of what happened with the execution of the procedure, so I have a kind of a log of the executions in another table.

Since the procedure will be executed every day to create a .txt but not every day will be available data in the where clause, I want to keep a log so the BU won't think it's an error

Comment: You only use the CTE in the `if` so just use `if exists (select * from... where)`...

Comment: Does your `PROCEDURE` do any DML (`INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE`) or only `SELECT`? If so, then you should move it to a `FUNCTION` (or even a `VIEW` if it has no parameters).

Comment: @Dai it does a bunch of updates and inserts. 

@Stu, I've tried the `if exists(select * form cte...)` it gives the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to call a CTE in a follow up IF statement

You can't, use a temp table instead, especially if you need re-usability or are trying to go for readability:

```
CREATE PROC st_exemple
AS
(...)

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Results;
SELECT 
    TABEL1.ID_COTA,
    TABLE2.NM_CLIENT
INTO #Results   
FROM (...)
WHERE(...);

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #Results)
  BEGIN
    SET @COMMENT = 'SELECT WTIHOUT DATA'
    GOTO END_PROC
  END;
ELSE
  BEGIN
      SET @COMMENT = 'SELECT WITH DATA';
      GOTO END_PROC
  END;
```

Comment: If you're populating a temp table you should just use `@@rowcount`, and note columns name aliases don't use `'` as delimiters and aren't needed in either of these cases.

Comment: @Stu True, good point (as long as `NOCOUNT` is off, which by default it is here), if there's no re-usability needed. But I'll leave it as is since OP didn't provide the whole procedure.

Comment: @Stu I'm not sure I follow your point about the aliases. It's valid syntax (albeit not my first choice) what OP did by using single quotes.

Comment: @Dai You don't need to check for the locally scoped temp table's existence, my line of code that does is only there by my preference for when running the code inline while testing. Not sure what your point is otherwise. Also, temp table's have a potential performance benefit that most people don't realize where SQL Server can re-use the schema and stats on future calls, which is not available for table variables.

Comment: @J.D. because that's what the [microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-identifiers?view=sql-server-ver16) describes.

Comment: @J.D. You are correct - I'm still averse to `#temp` tables in general though. As for the performance from reusing the schema, do you have a link to documentation on that?

Comment: @Stu, About the columns aliases, I know that. My original must have spaces in the name, i didnt noticed that I put undelines in my exemple. 
My proc also needs to have nocount on so i dont think @@rowcount would work. 
I will add it to my exemple, I didnt think it would make a diference. 

Thanks for your time !

Comment: @Dai temp tables in stored procedures (and any nested batch) are always dropped at the end of the proc (nested batch).

Comment: It's true that temp tables are not "actually" dropped and their meta data such as statistics are reused unless certain mitigating actions are taken - this is a pro and a con, depending.

Comment: @ArturCarreira `SET NOCOUNT` suppresses the textual "123 rows affected" message in TDS, it doesn't affect `@@ROWCOUNT`. I gather that it's recommended to use `SET NOCOUNT ON`  to prevent ambiguous TDS messages about "internal" DML being seen by clients that don't need to see them (along with `SET XACT_ABORT ON;`).

Comment: @Stu Local temp-tables exist as separate tables in tempdb, how can `STATISTICS` be re-used? they're table-scoped.

Comment: @Dai Got it! I will have a look on the @@rowcount then. I dont know very much how it works but im sure its nothing that some reading wont sufice  
Thanks again

Comment: @ArturCarreira That said, what do you want `@@ROWCOUNT` for, exactly? Is `OUTPUT` more helpful instead?

Comment: @dai - because internally SQL Server has various optimizations for tempDB in order to cope with creating and dropping temporary objects as quickly as possible; dropping a `#table` is faked, its metadata hangs around and can be reused by *other SPIDS* Brent Ozar's *fundamentals of tempDB* covers it in detail.

Comment: @Stu Thanks - I read a lot of Brent's stuff but I hadn't come across that article yet, I'll add it to my reading it.

Comment: @dai jsut to make sure the select is empty or not. 
I'm looking for ways to do it, so I can choose the one that fits the best. 
the options of #table or @table are good. 
I Might use the @table one. 

Ive found another way to... a bit ugly but works 
`SELECT @VALIDACAO_CTE = (SELECT 'V' WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM CTE)
                              UNION ALL
                           SELECT 'F' WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM CTE))`

Comment: @dai it's one of his paid training articles - sometimes he streams them for free and was doing so a couple of weeks ago, just the first module of 5 classes for 5 days, I managed to catch them.

Comment: The gory details about temp table object caching and stats are https://www.sql.kiwi/2012/08/temporary-tables-in-stored-procedures.html

Comment: @MartinSmith [Only $89? That's _suspiciously_ reasonable](https://training.brentozar.com/p/fundamentals-of-tempdb)

Comment: @Dai "*As for the performance from reusing the schema, do you have a link to documentation on that?*" - It actually does do include table variables too (TIL). I'd still go for temp tables for the stats benefits. Please see [Paul White's excellent article.](https://sqlperformance.com/2017/05/sql-performance/sql-server-temporary-object-caching). "*I'm still averse to #temp tables in general though.*" - Why? They're *almost* always better than table variables, with little drawbacks.

Comment: @J.D. Because when I'm just spitballing in SSMS it's never immediately obvious if a `#temp` table already exists or already contains data from prior in the session or across multiple SSMS sessions - having to constantly re-run `DROP IF EXISTS` before I do anything is a pain - and sometimes I'll run `DROP IF EXISTS` _by mistake_ out-of-habit and have to start all over again. With TVs I know it will always be reset when I re-run my current SSMS batch.

Comment: @Dai I suppose, though I've found the latest `DROP IF EXISTS` syntax pretty easy to get accustomed to always prefacing creation of local temp tables with. And with the drawbacks (mostly the hard-coded stats cardinality in the SQL Server Engine), I prefer going to the extra effort of coding an additional line to manage temp tables. I've improved execution times of queries literally 100-fold just from subbing out a table variable with a temp table (when appropriate), because of the improved query plan from them.